# Windows: WM_DPICHANGED and DPI request from monitor/DC differs

Tags: winapi, dpi, multiple-monitors

I'm new to the DPI awareness.

I activated the per monitor awareness and added the WM_DPICHANGED message handling and ran into problems.

1. While teh application starts I need to handle WM_DPICHANGED messages with WPARAM and LPARAM arguments equal to zero
2. Having two monitors set up with different display zooms (150/175) I expect to get a monitor aware DPI using `GetDeviceCaps`, if the window I use the DC from is on that monitor, but I get always the same DPI value of 144 (150%).
3. Asking for the monitor a window is displayed on and for its current display settings returns only 144 DPI, too, even if it is set up to 168 DPI (175%).

First the code I use to get in WM_DPICHANGED the device context dependent LOGPIXELS:

```
CDC* const pDC = GetDC();
const int nDcDpi = GetDeviceCaps(*pDC, LOGPIXELSX);
ReleaseDC(pDC);
```

The way I get the monitor dependent DPI while handling WM_DPICHANGED:

```
HMONITOR hMonitor = MonitorFromWindow(GetSafeHwnd(), MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL);
MONITORINFOEX mix;
mix.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFOEX);
GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &mix);

DEVMODE dm{ sizeof(DEVMODE) };
EnumDisplaySettings(mix.szDevice, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dm);

const WORD  nDmDpi = dm.dmLogPixels;
```

The DPI value provided to the WM_DPICHANGED handler I get this way:

```
const WORD  nWmDPI = LOWORD(wParam);
```

If the main window of my application moves from the Monitor 1 (144 DPI) to the Monitor 2 (168 DPI) the results in the WM_DPICHANGED handler are:

- 144 DPI from DEVMODE
- 144 DPI from HDC
- 168 DPI from WM_DPICHANGED

Can someone here explain me the differences?

And - if the application starts up, how to get the correct "zoom factor", the correct DPI value, if `GetDeviceCaps` does not return the correct value?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

Martin

Comment: The message provides you with the proposed RECT of the window.  But it isn't there yet so you still get the previous monitor.  Consider MonitorFromRect() to find the correct one.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn280510(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @HansPassant: I now used additionally the proposed RECT from WM_DPICHANGED to ask for the monitor and both ways show, that the correct monitor, the destination monitor is used to ask for the LOGPIXELS in the DEVMODE structure.
Even the device names in the MONITORINFOEX structure shows the correct name of the destination, not the source monitor.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov Thanks for your hint to "GetDpiForMonitor". Sincerely I can't use the function on Windows 10.
I first tried by including the correct header, then I used LoadLibrary and GetProcAdress, but even this call returned a nullptr.
Even GetScaleFactorForMonitor is not available - while I'm a bit concerned, since it cannot return 175%, which is my current setup for the 2nd Monitor.

Comment: Show your code where you use LoadLibrary and GetProcAdress.